# problem with frustum AABB culling in DirectX

Tags: collision-detection, directx, rendering, frustum

I am currently working on a project with a few friends, and I am trying to get frustum culling working.  Every single tutorial or article I go to shows that my math is correct and that this should be working.  I thought maybe posting here, somebody would catch something I could not.  Thank you.

Here are the important code snippets

```
     /create the projection matrix
void CD3DCamera::SetLens(float fov, float aspect, float nearZ, float farZ)
{
 D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&projMat, D3DXToRadian(fov), aspect, nearZ, farZ);
}

//build the view matrix after changes have been made to camera
void CD3DCamera::BuildView()
{
 //keep axes orthoganal
 D3DXVec3Normalize(&look, &look);

 //up
 D3DXVec3Cross(&up, &look, &right);
 D3DXVec3Normalize(&up, &up);

 //right
 D3DXVec3Cross(&right, &up, &look);
 D3DXVec3Normalize(&right, &right);

 //fill view matrix
 float x = -D3DXVec3Dot(&position, &right);
 float y = -D3DXVec3Dot(&position, &up);
 float z = -D3DXVec3Dot(&position, &look);

 viewMat(0,0) = right.x;
 viewMat(1,0) = right.y;
 viewMat(2,0) = right.z;
 viewMat(3,0) = x;

 viewMat(0,1) = up.x;
 viewMat(1,1) = up.y;
 viewMat(2,1) = up.z;
 viewMat(3,1) = y;

 viewMat(0,2) = look.x;
 viewMat(1,2) = look.y;
 viewMat(2,2) = look.z;
 viewMat(3,2) = z;

 viewMat(0,3) = 0.0f;
 viewMat(1,3) = 0.0f;
 viewMat(2,3) = 0.0f;
 viewMat(3,3) = 1.0f;
}

    void CD3DCamera::BuildFrustum()
{ 


 D3DXMATRIX VP;
 D3DXMatrixMultiply(&VP, &viewMat, &projMat);

 D3DXVECTOR4 col0(VP(0,0), VP(1,0), VP(2,0), VP(3,0));

 D3DXVECTOR4 col1(VP(0,1), VP(1,1), VP(2,1), VP(3,1));

 D3DXVECTOR4 col2(VP(0,2), VP(1,2), VP(2,2), VP(3,2));

 D3DXVECTOR4 col3(VP(0,3), VP(1,3), VP(2,3), VP(3,3));

 // Planes face inward
 frustum[0] = (D3DXPLANE)(col2);    // near
 frustum[1] = (D3DXPLANE)(col3 - col2);  // far
 frustum[2] = (D3DXPLANE)(col3 + col0);  // left
 frustum[3] = (D3DXPLANE)(col3 - col0);  // right
 frustum[4] = (D3DXPLANE)(col3 - col1);  // top
 frustum[5] = (D3DXPLANE)(col3 + col1);  // bottom

 // Normalize the frustum
 for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
  D3DXPlaneNormalize( &frustum[i], &frustum[i] );


}

    bool FrustumCheck(D3DXVECTOR3 max, D3DXVECTOR3 min, const D3DXPLANE* frustum)
{
 // Test assumes frustum planes face inward.

 D3DXVECTOR3 P;
 D3DXVECTOR3 Q;
 bool ret = false;


 for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
 {
  // For each coordinate axis x, y, z...
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
  {
   // Make PQ point in the same direction as the plane normal on this axis.
   if( frustum[i][j] > 0.0f )
   {
    P[j] = min[j];
    Q[j] = max[j];
   }
   else 
   {
    P[j] = max[j];
    Q[j] = min[j];
   }
  }


  if(D3DXPlaneDotCoord(&frustum[i], &Q) < 0.0f  )
   ret = false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: you set the variable ret = true/false, but you just return true explicitly, is this a "typo" or actual code error?

Comment: sorry typo, its really a return false there instead of setting it to false

Comment: Thank you for looking at the code, everyone that did, I have fixed the problem.  The problem was that our level editor's coordinate system was flipped on the x axis.  So what we had to do was flip the x on the vectors of the min/max of the bounding boxes so that they were accurate.  However, eventually we will go back and fix the level editor so that it has the correct coordinate system. lol

Comment: Could help if you put that in an answer and accept it in case anyone else runs into a similar problem :)

Comment: @Matthew Poole: what happens to P?  You compute it but don't test it?

Comment: @Will Here he has computed P unnecessarily. It is used for detecting if the box is partially inside : `if(D3DXPlaneDotCoord(&frustum[i], &P) < 0.0f ) return INTERSECTING;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for looking at the code, everyone that did, I have fixed the problem. The problem was that our level editor's coordinate system was flipped on the x axis. So what we had to do was flip the x on the vectors of the min/max of the bounding boxes so that they were accurate. However, eventually we will go back and fix the level editor so that it has the correct coordinate system. lol